# Redefinition of tuple when using gtest and google sparsehash

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, googletest, sparsehash

All test cases that somehow include `<gtest/gtest.h>` and `<google/dense_hash_map>` fail to build for me. Usually the later is included indirectly but I can reproduce the problem like this:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <google/dense_hash_map>

TEST(SparsehashTest, justPass) {
  ASSERT_TRUE(true);
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The problem:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/tr1/functional:39:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/sparsehash/dense_hash_map:106,
                 from /usr/local/include/google/dense_hash_map:34,
                 from /home/me/xxx/test/SparsehashTest.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/tuple:130:11: error: redefinition of ‘class std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >’
     class tuple : public _Tuple_impl<0, _Elements...>
           ^
In file included from /home/me/xxx/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:697:0,
                 from /home/me/xxx/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40,
                 from /home/me/xxx/third_party/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58,
                 from /home/me/xxx/test/SparsehashTest.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/5/tuple:463:11: error: previous definition of ‘class std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >’
     class tuple : public _Tuple_impl<0, _Elements...>
```

So sparsehash includes `/usr/include/c++/5/tr1/tuple` whereas gtest includes `/usr/include/c++/5/tuple` and puts it in the tr1 namespace in **gtest-port.h:**

```
...
697: #include <tuple>
698: // C++11 puts its tuple into the ::std namespace rather than
699: // ::std::tr1.  gtest expects tuple to live in ::std::tr1, so put it there.
700: // This causes undefined behavior, but supported compilers react in
701: // the way we intend.
702: namespace std {
703: namespace tr1 {
704: using ::std::get;
705: using ::std::make_tuple;
706: using ::std::tuple;
707: using ::std::tuple_element;
708: using ::std::tuple_size;
709: }
...
```

I can understand why this causes problems, but so far I don't understand why this only seems to happen in my setup.
I have google-sparsehash installed regularly (`git clone` and then `./configure && make && sudo make install`) and my project is a CMake project that has a git submode for googletest and builds it as a dependency / subfolder. This setup works as intended for all tests that do not (indirectly) include the sparsehash headers.

**EDIT: So it seems to compile if I add `-DGTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE=0 -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0` as compiler flags. I'm not sure why this is necessary and if it's the right thing to do here**

Comment: bless you that worked: -DGTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE=0 -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=0

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread because I had the same issue, and it provided enough clues that I managed to fix my issue by requesting that sparsehash be compiled with the c++11 compiler option:

./configure CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'

Answer (score 0):

The full set of defines altering gtest due to environmment are shown in [gtest-port.h](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h#4-) file. The documentation also gives you [the detail of TR1 tuple configuration](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/README.md#choosing-a-tr1-tuple-library).

Depending on your environment. You may be doing the right thing. GoogleTest is supposed to do the detection for you, in practice I've rarely seen it work and I usually define the same flags as yours.